# OpenGL apps not responding to touch on Xperia M2

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, touchscreen, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia M2 (not rooted, on stock 4.3 Jellybean). When installing some apps, I noticed they won't respond to touches. After installing a few more apps it became apparent that the apps that didn't respond to touches all used OpenGL. Other apps work perfectly, but ones with OpenGL get stuck.

The apps aren't frozen because any background animations they have still work fine.

With developer mode visual touch feedback enabled, my touches show up on screen, so I know android still registers them.

What's going on, and how do I fix this?
Also, will updating to KitKat affect this in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to 4.4 KitKat and the problem seemed to have been solved. All OpenGL apps now work like normal.